# Why do people steal less stuff than they should?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm in the maxing out stage of my Town Hall 8 village, which means I don't use elixir much, and I have full elixir storages all the time, with a capacity of 6,000,000 elixir (3 level 11 storages).

According to the [wiki](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Elixir_Storage), level 11 elixir storages give 10% of their current resources when destroyed during an attack. There is a maximum cap for amount of elixir stolen from storages, which is 450,000 elixir.

However, most of the times when my village gets completely destroyed, 3-star raid, the amount of elixir stolen is only about 350,000. This is way less than the maximum cap or 10% of the resources, and I'm not even taking into account collectors, the Town Hall and the Clan Castle.

Why?

Comment: what level townhall do the people have who are attacking you?

Comment: Mostly level 9, sometimes even level 10.

Comment: The title of this question looks really weird out-of-context.

Comment: @pppery That's why it's important to write titles that accurately reflect what their asking rather than generic, vague things that could apply to any number of questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a higher townhall level than you attacks you, they suffer a loot penalty. The current loot penalty is show in the following graph.
[image]

You can also find out more on how the loot you can get is calculated [here](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Raids) under section "Loot".